# Sheet.Activate changes sheet but continues to edit data on previous sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have a dialog box with a couple of buttons that launch macros to activate and change to different sheets.

The problem I am having is after I click the button, the macro activates the new sheet and I see it. But when I go to delete data, add data or try to delete a row "Nothing happens" the data on the screen is still there.  If I go back to the previous sheet, the cells and rows that I had intended to delete were deleted in that sheet.  It is very wierd and never seen anything like that.  It appears that my macro code is note doing enough to actually change to the new sheet.  I do not have this problem if I click a different sheet tab to change to it.  Or if I click the dialog button to go to the new sheet and quickly do a ctrl-pgDown and Ctrl-PgUp to change from another tab and back that seems to fix the problem.

This is the code in my macro I am using to try to change to the desired tab.

```
Private Sub Report1Button_Click()
On Error GoTo Handler
Sheets("Report1").Activate
If StayOpenBox.Value = False Then
    Unload MainMenu
End If
Exit Sub
Handler:
MsgBox "Sheet 'Report1' not found or renamed"
End Sub
```

Thanks for any help or suggestions

UPDATE:

Here is code that I use to call the dialog box.  I have a shape on the other sheet that is assigned to this macro to open dialog box

```
Sub ShowMainMenu()

With UserForm1
  .Show
End With
End Sub
```

Also there is no further code to make edits to the new sheet.  My Button click simply switches to the other sheet and when I attempt to make edits manually, they are actually done on the previous sheet which is not the one I am currently looking at.  So anything I do,  Bold text, delete text, delete row, etc, is not done on the current sheet I am looking at, but when I return to the previous sheet the changes where made there.  Im on Excel 2013, I have reproduced this problem in 2 separate files, but I will try on a different computer and older version of excel.  Screenshot of my situation is below.

[image: Screenshot of Code]

UPDATE 2:
I ran this xlsm file on a 2nd computer with Xls 2007 and was not having the problem.  So I ran the macro on a 3rd computer that also has Excel 2013 and it is experiencing the same problem.  So it is not computer specific and seems to be a problem in XLS 2013 but not in XLS 2007.  I will try to find a computer with Excel 2010 to test as well, but something about this code is causing a problem in 2013 but not in older versions of excel.

Comment: Both of the answers below make sense both dont address my issue.  VBA codes does correctly activate the correct sheet and excel changes to that sheet.  But when I try to edit it continues to edit the previous sheet.  I have discovered if I run the macro directly or assign macro to a shape, Excel will activate the correct sheet and I will not have a problem editing.  BUT I have the macro assigned to a command button_click and that seems to be part of the problem for some reason.

Comment: There must be some more code to fire the UserForm MainMenu. Report1Button_Click is on MainMenu isn't it? Could you also post the code that makes the changes to Report1 because all the posted code does is activate it then possibly Unload MainMenu?

Comment: @user1825774 Yes, we would need to see your code as an edit to your original post.

Comment: I  have created a ribbon customization that runs macro code for sheet activation and there are no problems with editing the new sheet after that .  Problem exists when a button in a dialog box activates the sheet, and only in Excel 2013, Excel 2007 is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `VBA` code, it will default to using the `ActiveSheet` if you don't define the Sheet.  When you have objects/methods that you want performed on a specific sheet, you should always specify!  You can do that one of two ways:

```
Sheets("Report1").[Object].[Method]
'or
Sheets("Report1").[Method]
```

or you can pass the Sheet name to a variable and use that for shorter code

```
Dim Report1 As Worksheet
Set Report1 = Sheets("Report1")
Report1.[Object].[Method]
'or
Report1.[Method]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the sequence of lines in your code. I had a similar situation and it turned out that I inserted the "delete sheet" code in between the commands that were copying data from sheet1 to sheet2. When I put the deletion lines (commands) after I finished copying sheets everything started to work correctly. Many commands activate one sheet while performing and this immediately disactivates another sheet. So if you used "ActiveSheet" sommand somewhere it may be incorrectly understood - the command may be executed not on the sheet you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the full address for the range you are trying to manipulate, for example instead of:

```
Sheets("mySheet").Activate
Range("A1:B10").Cut
Sheets("myOtherSheet").Activate
Range("A1:B10").Paste
```

use:

```
Sheets("mySheet").Range("A1:A10").Cut Destination:=Sheets("myOtherSheet").Range("A1:B10")
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, also with Excel 2013. So even if the thread is over 9 month inactive, I want to share my solution in case somebody gets here through a Google search.

The solution was really simple. Call the userform with:

```
UserForm1.show vbModeless
```